# Microservices - Maintaining Multiple Data stores, initial data load etc

Tags: microservices

On aspects of granulatiry of mictoservices have read about the 2 pizza rule, services that can be developed in 2 weeks etc.  When the case studies of amazon, nelflix, gilt are read we hear about 100s of services. While the service granularity does make sense, what is still not clear to me is about the data stores of each of these microservices. Will there not be just too many data stores if each of the services store/maintain their own data ?? It might be the same logical entity like a product, customer etc that is sliced & the relevant portion/attributes stored/maintained by a corresponding microservice. There could be a service that maintains basic customer information, another that maintains the additional customer information like say his subscription information or his interests etc.

Couple of questions that come to mind around the data stores

1. Will this not be a huge maintenance issue in terms of backups,
   restores etc?
2. How is the initial data populated into these stores ? Are there any best practices around this ? Organisations are bound to have huge volumes of customer or product data & they will most likely be mastered in other systems.
3. How does this approach of multiple data stores impact the 'omni-channel' approach where it  implies getting a single view of all data? Organizations might have had data consolidation initiatives going on to achieve the same

Edit: Edited the subject a bit

Comment: This is not question for SO, You should ask it on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @luboskrnac - This wouldn't fit well on Programmers either.  It's too broad and a bit unclear as to what's actually being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.Will this not be a huge maintenance issue in terms of backups, restores etc?
```

From your view yes it will. I mean at the end of day you will not have just one database server to backup but tens or hundreds of them. But mostly people -at least that is what we do - is using a cloud database service to get rid of all these maintenance effort.

```
2.How is the initial data populated into these stores ? Are there any best practices around this ? Organisations are bound to have huge volumes of customer or product data & they will most likely be mastered in other systems.
```

I am not sure if there is a best way but we created a client to read the data from legacy system then convert and split it into the parts for each microservices and push them to those microservices by consuming their services. We used message queues to to be sure about health of migration.

```
3.How does this approach of multiple data stores impact the 'omni-channel' approach where it implies getting a single view of all data? Organizations might have had data consolidation initiatives going on to achieve the same.
```

Well I don't know what "omni-channel" is so I can't answer that.

Lastly you were mentioning about logical entities shared between services. The real hardest part about implementing microservices is defining what each service will provide. And while doing that you should carefully examine data needs for each services and those services should share as little as possible like only entity ids etc. At least that is what we are doing.

Comment: Your reply came in just as I was reading some meta posts on mechanism to move this question to programmers.SE :-) On Q2, Do you always use services for ingesting the data from the legacy system to the microservice system. While I understand that, the recommendation is to not allow anybody to access the microservice repository directly, I wonder how this works for the initial dataload when the records are in the millions. There might even be some daily delta updates from legacy that needs to be brought in which could be in the thousands.

Comment: On Q3, we hear a lot of solutions that move towards a 'single source of truth' repositories out of which all channels (web, mobile or store operations or customer service) work. But in the microservices world the talk is around denormalization & having multiple repositories. I was wondering if these are contradictions.  Would the approach be to do away with 'single source of truth' repositories & provide the 'single source of truth' at a service layer rather than a repository layer ?

Comment: For your first comment we actually implemented some special services just for migration.

Comment: IMHO using repos is not useful because the real know-how and value is not in there but in domain model to which you can access through the services. In addition there would be so many issues like configuration management problems if you try to use repos directly. I mean when you use services to integrate systems those services would become the contract between the systems and managing those is quite easy especially with all that SOA and web services stuff. If you move that integration layer to repositories changing database model, database technology or even vendors will be impossible.